# NodeJS/MongoDB: Only connect one time to DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm doing some e2e tests of a nodeJS application. In the before/after hooks I need to add/remove some mongoDB documents and this is how I do that:

Shouldn't it be possible to connect only one time to the mongo server at all?

What I would like to do:

1. Remove all documents `{ _id: articleId }` at the beginning (right now missing in the code)
2. Insert new document to DB (`collection.insertOne(articles.main)`)
3. Remove all documents after the tests has be finished

My code feels not very good to me

```
describe('article module', function () {
  before(function () {
    MongoClient.connect(mongoServer, (err, db) => {
      expect(err).to.be.null
      db.collection('content', (err, collection) => {
        expect(err).to.be.null
        collection.findOne({ _id: articleId }, (err, item) => {
          expect(err).to.be.null
          if (!item) collection.insertOne(articles.main)
          db.close()
        })
      })
    })
  })

  after(function () {
    MongoClient.connect(mongoServer, (err, db) => {
      expect(err).to.be.null
      db.collection('content', (err, collection) => {
        expect(err).to.be.null
        collection.remove({ _id: articleId }, (err, removed) => {
          expect(err).to.be.null
          db.close()
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Just put it into a function and call that function...........................

Comment: You can actually chain this using promises, it'll make it cleaner

Comment: @AvinduHewa Could you post a code example?

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with what you have, I'd say it's cleaner to open a connection when needed as opposed to keeping an active connection opened for the full spec (unless `connect` yields a poolable connection).

Comment: @James Ok, thanks for that. I was thinking connecting once would be better... So I will keep everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
describe('article module', () => {
  before(() => {

    MongoClient.connect(mongoServer, (err, db) => {
      expect(err).to.be.null

      const content = db.collection('content');

      content.findOne({ _id: articleId })
      .then(item => {
        return content.insertOne(articles.main);
      })
      .then(insertResult => {
        db.close();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        expect(err).to.be.null;
      })
    })

  })

  after(() => {
    MongoClient.connect(mongoServer, (err, db) => {
      expect(err).to.be.null

      const content = db.collection('content');

      content.remove({ _id: articleId })
      .then(removed => {
        db.close();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        expect(err).to.be.null;
      })
    })
  })
})
```

You can call the db using a third party promise as well

Comment: I hope it helped , but i dont understand the downvote